# Cannot pass parameter by reference in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, binding, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to pass a string into my MySQLi prepared statement but it gives me the error:

Cannot pass parameter by reference in MySQLi

Here is the relevant code:

```
$kv = json_encode(array($key => $value));
$stmt->prepare("insert into rules (application_id, ruletype, rule_name, rule_info) values (?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_param('iiss', $application_id, 1, $config_name, $kv);
```

Comment: Why not simply embed the `'1'` directly into the query? If it's a static value, there's no point in making it a bound parameter. Otherwise, simply do `$one = 1;` and then pass in `$one` into the bind call. You can't make a reference to a constant.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

'1' cannot be passed by reference because it's not a variable but a literal. You need to create a variable with mentioned value and bind it instead because `bind_param()` function expects variables passed by reference.

Comment: Note that the first string is not a parameter, those are the **Type specification chars**, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad - I skimmed trough the question and noticed that OP isn't passing an argument as variable. I'll edit the answer with your input.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. One of the dumbest concepts I've ever seen (this is not directed towards you but towards the devs who wrote this function). As far as I understand, the idea behind it was to allow changing the passed values after calling prepare() and bind_param(), but no dev in their right mind would write sequential code like that, because it is predestined to cause logical errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$config_name` argument. `'1'` not pass as refernces